# Use HTML Checkbox with formula.js

Tags: javascript, html, excel, formula.js

I use a website called Appizy to convert excel files to html/css/javascript. It generally works for my purpose as I am very proficient with excel and am usually able to tweak the final web based code through monkeying around with it or trial and error.

Below is the javascript code that was converted from an excel if/then statement.

```
s1r3c1: function() { APY.set('s1r3c1',formulajs.IF(APY.RANGE([1,3,0])=="x",formulajs.TRUE(),formulajs.FALSE())) },
    };
```

In excel language I think this is saying that If a certain cell equals "X", then display True or False. Is there a way to tweak this to replace the "X" in this formula with a linked checkbox being turned on or off? I really have zero clue how to proceed. I am able to create a checkbox element in the HTML section of the code so it appears where I want it, but don't understand how to make it work.

I hope I have conveyed this clearly but if not, let me know and I will try to clarify. Thank you so much.

Comment: You should give your checkbox an `id`, e.g., `<input type="checkbox" id="ck_s1r3c1">` and get its status in javascript with `document.getElementById("ck_s1r3c1").checked`. But I didn't understand how you plan to use that in your formula function....

Comment: Hi Thank you for your reply! And sorry for my late one. Is there a way to replace the "if" part of my function `APY.RANGE([1,3,0])=="x"` to receive whether a checkbox elsewhere in the document is checked or not?

Comment: In javascript proper it would be exactly that, `APY.RANGE([1 ,3 , 0]) == "x"`, which evaluates to `true` or `false`, equivalent to `formulajs.TRUE()` and `formulajs.FALSE()`

Comment: OK, did not know that...So if I start with `<input type="checkbox" id="ck_s1r3c1">`, how would I set checked to equal `TRUE` and unchecked to be `FALSE`. How would I get the IF formula to interact with, it in other words?

Comment: From the spreadsheet to the checkbox it should work by adding the code `document.getElementById("ck_s1r3c1").checked = APY.RANGE([1 ,3 , 0]) == "x"` inside the function `s1r3c1`, after the `APY.SET` call (with a semicolon between them).

Comment: The other way around is not that easy... it depends on the overall structure of the existing code, specifically, how can we get to call the function `s1r3c1` from the top level of the script

Comment: `s1r0c0: function() { APY.set(document.getElementById("ID").checked = APY.RANGE([1 ,3 , 0]) == "x"",formulajs.TRUE(),formulajs.FALSE())) }` Am I close?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248817/discussion-between-kikon-and-z-doe).